# Detect path name changes in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some functionality that i need to change whenever the path changes. Often you would solve that problem with the following.

```
myProp: ( ->
  # .. Do something here
).property('currentPath')
```

The problem with currentPath, is that it only detect route changes, so the following transition is not detected.

```
/blog/my-awesome-blog-post -> /blog/new-awesome-post
```

Because they are working on the same route, but i need to detect when a transition like that happens, as i need to update my social media sharing links.

I have tried something like the following with no luck.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  conf: config,
  currentPathName: '',
});

App.initializer({
  name: 'Path name observer',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var router = container.lookup('router:main');

    router.addObserver('url', function() {
      var lastUrl = undefined;
      return function() {
        Ember.run.next(function() {
          var url = router.get('url');
          if (url !== lastUrl) {
            App.set('currentPathName', url);
            lastUrl = url;
          }
        });
      };
    }());
  }
});
```

And then observe 'App.currentPathName', but this somehow messes the router up, as the url's suddenly doesn't change on click.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution i got from a friendly soul @ github. This is not currently documented, but works quiet nicely.

```
Ember.Router.reopen({
  doSomethingOnUrlChange: function() {
    console.log(this.get('url'));
  }.on('didTransition')
});
```

Comment: It rather should be `App.Router.reopen()`.